# fscanf and printf stop working

Tags: c

I tried to read and print words from a text file, but the program somehow closed itself.

```
int main(){
    FILE * test= fopen("book.txt","r");
    char *wp;
    while(!feof(test))
    {
        wp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        fscanf(test,"%s",wp);
        printf("%s",(char)wp);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You only allocated one byte for `wp`. And casting `wp` to `char` makes no sense.

Comment: Casting `char` to `wp` means you're trying to print the value in memory location from `0` to `255`. This is not allowed, so the unexpected closing.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in your code that I'm just going to show you a proper way to do it.

```
// Include needed header files.
#include <stdio.h>  // fopen, fprintf, fgets, printf, fclose
#include <stdlib.h> // exit, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h> // strchr

int main(){
    // Allocate more than enough space to hold a line.
    char line[256];

    FILE *file = fopen("book.txt","r");

    // Ensure that file has opened.
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Return an integer indicating failure.
    }

    // Use fgets to avoid buffer overflow.
    // Test for end-of-file directly with the input function.    
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        // Remove newline if present
        char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
        if (p != NULL) *p = '\0';

        printf("%s\n", line);
    }

    // Explicitly close file.
    fclose(file);    

    return 0;   // Return an integer (0 or EXIT_SUCCESS indicates success)
}
```